# How could I start/display a file in lua, like the batch command "start"?

Tags: batch-file, lua, command-prompt

I have looked into opening/starting files in lua, however every single article is giving me functions like dofile() that returns/runs the file status/contents, instead of actually opening/starting the file. In my scenario I have a .hta file that I am trying to start through lua, what I am technically wondering is if lua has a function kind of like the batch command "start", that starts a file, if not is there any method to send commands to a console from a lua file? If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know what lua is. But hta are run by mshta.exe. so do `mshta c:\folder\file.hta`. According to your language you use `os.execute ([command])` -  https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.9

Comment: `os.execute[["c:\path\to\your\file.hta"]]` is the simplest method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [os.execute()](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.execute). It allows you to run a command in an operating system shell:

```
local code = os.execute("ls -la")
if code ~= 0 then
    print("Something when wrong while running command")
end
```

If you also want to capture the output from the executed command and use it in your Lua code you can use [io.popen()](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen):

```
local f = assert(io.popen("ls -la", 'r'))
local output = assert(f:read('*a'))
f:close()
print(output)
```

Note that io.popen() isn't available on all systems.